# How to increase the number of geoserver's workers and the geoserver's performance

Tags: geoserver

ı want to make a base map in geoserver but geoserver is too slow.
More than one tileserver can be run on a server. How do I run multiple geoservers on one server

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: In general see the manual - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/index.html#production